# Storing and retrieving student scores in three subjects

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, hash-map

This is written to find percentages of three subjects. Original HackerRank practice problem is [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/finding-the-percentage).

> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains the integer *N*, the number of students. The next  *N* lines contains the name and marks obtained by that student separated by a space. The final line contains the name of a particular student previously listed.
>
> #### Output Format
>
> Print one line: The average of the marks obtained by the particular student correct to 2 decimal places.

This code is working but I need better way of writing this code.

```
a = input()
a = int(a)
dict = {}
f = []
n = {}
for i in range(a):
        f = input().split()
        name = f[0]
        n['phy'] = float(f[1])
        n['che'] = float(f[2])
        n['math'] = float(f[3])
        f = []
        dict[name] = n
        n ={}
nam = input();
per = (dict[nam]['phy']+dict[nam]['che']+dict[nam]['math'])/3
print("%.2f"%per)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PEP 8, the official Python style guide, specifies [four spaces per level of indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).  Since whitespace is significant in Python, that is a pretty strong convention.

The challenge states that the first line contains *N*, the number of students.  So, don't call that value `a` in the code, and don't use the variable `n` to mean something else.  It's confusing.

The variable `i` is never used.  It is customary to use `_` as the name of a "throwaway" variable whose value does not matter.

Clearing `f` and `n` at the end of the loop is cumbersome and unnecessary.  Avoid cryptic variable names like `f` and `n` whose meanings are not obvious.  Even names like `nam` and `per` are unnecessarily unfriendly.  (Learn from [Ken Thompson's biggest regret](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/10893/17535).)

For this problem, there is no need to store the scores for each subject separately.  You can just store the average right away.

```
scores = {}
n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    line = input().split()
    name = line.pop(0)
    scores[name] = sum(float(score) for score in line) / len(line)
print("%.2f" % scores[input()])
```